# Weka: why getMargin returns all zeros?

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I am using Weka Java API. I trained a Bayesnet on an Instances object (data set) `data`.

```
/**
 * Initialization
 */
Instances data = ...;
BayesNet bn = new EditableBayesNet(data);
SearchAlgorithm learner = new TAN();
SimpleEstimator estimator = new SimpleEstimator();
/**
 * Training
 */
bn.initStructure();
learner.buildStructure(bn, data);
estimator.estimateCPTs(bn);
```

`getMargin` returns marginal distibution for a node. Ideally, assuming node `A` has 3 possible values, and its node index is 0. Then, `bn.getMargin(0)` should return something like `[0.3, 0.4, 0.3]`.

However, in my case, when I print marginal distributions of all nodes using the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i <bn.getNrOfNodes(); i++)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bn.getMargin(i)));
```

It returns

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...]
...
```

Someone has seen this before or can possibly give me some hints why this happens?

My data are nominal and most of the columns have many classes/values.

Answer (score 0):

I think I saw something like this in the GUI. When I had MaxnrofParents = 2, I could see the margins in the Bayes Editor, but if I used MaxnrofParents of anything bigger, the margins didn't show anything.